# How can I select all the row and column A1 to A3 in this function?

Tags: r

```
#Create a matrix
A1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
A2 <- c(6,7,8,9,10)
A3 <- c(11,12,13,14,15)
y <- c(16,17,18,19,20)
x1 <- c(A1,A2,A3,y)
x1.matrix <- matrix(x1,byrow = T,nrow=4)
names <- c('a','b','c','d','e')
x1.name <- c('A1','A2','A3','y')
colnames(x1.matrix) <- names
rownames(x1.matrix) <- x1.name
x1.df <- as.data.frame(t(x1.matrix))
print(x1.df)
#lasso with fixed lambda=10 (using lars)      #Do I chose a right Lambda?
a<-c(-10:10)/10
lambda<- 10^a
x2 <- model.matrix(A1~A3,data = x1.df)
```

how to select column A1 to A3 in this function. 
The A1~A3 here is wrong. it only gives me the value for A3. 
How can I fix this problem?

```
object <- lars(x=x2, y=x1.df[,4], type="lasso")   
betal <- coef(object, s=lambda, mode="lambda")
```

Comment: Probably `~ A1 + A2 + A3` for the formula...or `~ . - y` for all variables except `y`.

Comment: Thank you, Gregor. They are both works.

Comment: Hello Gregor, I fix that problem now but when I run the object it gives me this error message "Error in if (Cmax < eps * 100) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(y) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"